# How to create a generalized regex (POSIX) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: regex, postgresql, posix

In postgreSQL (9.5), PgAdmin III, I would like to generalize this POSIX statement for two words:

This works for the words 'new' and 'intermediate' with word boundaries:

```
select * from cpt where cdesc ~* '^(?=.*\mnew\M)(?=.*\mintermediate\M)'
```

This fails ( the "where" argument is seen as a text string):

```
select * from cpt where cdesc ~* '^(?=.*\m'||'new'||'\M)(?=.*\mintermediate\M)'
```

How can this be written for a generlized function, e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getDesc(string1 text, string2 text)
  RETURNS SETOF cpt AS
$BODY$ 

select * from cpt where cdesc ~* '^(?=.*\m$1\M)(?=.*\m$2\M)'

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

(where $1 is string1 and $2 is string2)

TIA

Edit. Match stings in cdesc would be:

- "This is a new and intermediate art work"
- "This is an intermediate and new piece of art"

Non-match would be:

- "This is new art"
- "This is intermediate art"

Please note the order of the words is not important as long as both are present. Also, either word may have a punctuation mark -- (comma or period)--immediately following the word (no space).

Comment: what exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: @MarZab Sorry for not including that. Please see Edit with match and non-match. Essentially, the words "new" and "intermediate" both need to be ANYWHERE in the sentence and a comma,"," or period , "." could immediately follow the word (without a space). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to split the expensive regex into two SQL WHERE clauses and:

- matching with LIKE, as it is much faster, you can filter in code for more specific matches,
- or matching with a simple regex, something like '\m$1[\M,.]'

As for the regex you are using:

- I have not used it in a while, but I think you need parenthesis for string concatination

`~* ( '^(?=.*\m' || 'new' || '\M)(?=.*\mintermediate\M)' )`

Comment: Yep...Just got that. How can I allow the word to allow a punctuation mark to immediately follow the word? Thanks.

Comment: make a choice group, something like [\M,.]

Comment: Discovered that apparently \M already handles punctuation at end of word and there is no need for a choice group. Thanks.